# Which subversion control software should/can we use for a small organisation

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm fairly new to subversion and we're trying to improve our workflow and create better flexibility.

So, what's the best subversion control software for us to use in this situation? We're a small group (1 to 3 programmers). The languages we're dealing with are C# and Flex.

We've tried *VisualSVN* server with *TortoiseSVN*, but are there better/smaller/faster/... solutions for us?

Could you suggest other configurations/software worth checking out?

Comment: Add another developer and you'll have a GOF (group of four), hehe.

Comment: What do you find missing in the SVN implementations you have already tried?

Comment: We're a team of 2, and we're perfectly happy with Tortoise SVN...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with VisualSVN Server on the backend, as it is free and deals with all the hassle of setting up and serving the repository.

Once you have that as a base, you pretty much have free reign to choose the client side app that suits the individual. Some people prefer deep Visual studio integration, windows integration or the command-line. Or all three at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for client wich has the visual studio and windows integration? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't a single client that provides both shell integration and VS integration.

Personally, I think that TortoiseSVN is pretty much essential, for its shell integration, as I often have to work with files that aren't within a VS solution. It also makes branching and merging a lot easier.

For VS integration I've used VisualSVN, Tam Tam SVN and AnkhSVN. I ended up using the Ankh v2 the most - it is free and seemed to do the job reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding VisualSVN to the mix would allow you to do some work directly from Visual Studio. But beside this I think your configuration is perfect.

Comment: I'm currently evaluating AnkhSVN with Visual SVN Server and Tortoise SVN for "non Visual Studio projects". This works just great.

Answer (score 0):

Command line interface. Both for the server, and the client. Can't be any better, smaller, and faster.

Comment: This depends a lot on how comfortable each one on the team is with command line interfaces. If they are *not* comfortable with CLIs, then this is a sure way to turn them away from SVN for good.

Comment: I'm not at all comfortable with CLI's. So that's not an option. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: CLI SVN better? I couldn't disagree more, *especially* for those new to SVN. It's far too simple to make silly mistakes with the CLI client, like forgetting to add that file you just created and not noticing until AFTER people start complaining that the code no longer builds. With TortoiseSVN, you get a nice dialog showing non-versioned files as well, so it's easier to see the problem. Also, it's much easier to only commit SOME of your changes, since you can just deselect what you don't want, instead of specifying a complete list of what you want to commit. That's MUCH more user-friendly.